# Who can tell me the properties for the delta function in Sato's theory?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

In Sato's theory, the following formal delta function is defined:

$\delta(\lambda,z)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(\frac{z}{\lambda})^n=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\lambda/z}+\frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{1}{1-z/\lambda}$

Given a function 
$f(z)=\sum a_iz^i$,

$f(\lambda)\delta(\lambda,z)=f(z)\delta(\lambda,z)$.

I want to know the properties as many as possible. Or useful references are welcome to be provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formal delta function obeys the usual properties that the Dirac delta function does, but relative to the pairing defined by the residue.  For instance,
$$ \mathrm{Res}_z f(z)\delta(z,w) = f(w)$$
for any formal distribution $f(z)$.

This and more can be found in Kac's [*Vertex algebras for beginners*](http://books.google.com/books?id=PIhm9-37IlUC), particularly Proposition 2.1 in §2.1.

Comment: thanks for the answer, which is very helpful. I want to know whether the following relation is right,

$\delta(-\lambda,z+\mu-\lambda)=???\delta(-\mu,z)$

Thanks again.

Comment: I think so.  Although formally $\delta(x,y)$ is not a "function" of $x-y$, for all practical purposes it is.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Kac's excellent book I thought I'd mention [Vertex algebras and algebraic curves](http://books.google.com/books?id=mRgqy1f1QkIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=vertex+algebras+and+algebraic+curves&cd=1#v=onepage&q=vertex%20algebras%20and%20algebraic%20curves&f=false) by Ed Frenkel and me, which goes a little more into formal delta functions, D-modules and the like --- see section 1.1 and chapter 19 (2nd edition) in particular.